# How to prove that $\omega^{j\frac{2\pi}{7}}$ is one of the roots of cyclotomic equation?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, proof-writing

The number $\omega^{j\frac{2\pi}{7}}$ is one of the roots of the cyclotomic equation $x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = 0$.
How can I prove it? 
And is there any theory about numbers like $\omega^{j\frac{\pi}{p}}$, where p is a prime and its relation to cyclotomic equations?

Thanks!

Comment: Multiply $x-1$.

Comment: What is $w$.?.$e$.?

Answer (score 1):

$$(x-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=x^7-1=0$$
And $e^{j\frac{2\pi}7}$ is one of roots of $x^7-1=0$. All the roots of $x^7-1=0$ are $$\left\{e^{j\frac{2\pi k}7}|0\le k\le 6\right\}$$
All the roots of $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=0$ are $$\left\{e^{j\frac{2\pi k}7}|1\le k\le 6\right\}$$
This doesn't apply when 7 was not a prime number. In case of $6$,
$$(x-1)(x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=x^6-1=(x^3)^2-1=(x^2)^3-1=0$$
So root of $x^2=1$ and $x^3=-1$ are the roots.

Comment: It is not true you need it being prime

Answer (score 0):

For $z_0=\omega^{j\frac{2\pi}{7}}$ we have
$$z_0^7 = \left(\omega^{j\frac{2\pi}{7}}\right)^7 = \omega^{2\pi j} = \cos2\pi+j\sin2\pi = 1$$
so $z_0$ is the root of $z^7=1$ or $(z-1)(z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)=0$, but
$$z_0 = \omega^{j\frac{2\pi}{7}} = \cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+j\sin\frac{2\pi}{7} \neq 1$$
this concludes that $z_0$ is the root of $z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0$.

For $z_p=\omega^{j\frac{2\pi}{p}}$ with prime $p$, we have similar situation.